# Alternative ways to read excel in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel

Now I'm facing with a problem of reading excel file on SharePoint server.

In the old ways I usually use the OLEDB to read excel through the connection string, but it's just work on 32 bit system, then I attempt to convert my app to x86 platform target, but unfortunately my app (is a WebPart) which SharePoint is not allowed to work with.

I do many googling and hearing SharePoint Module (Microsoft.SharePoint.dll) can do that but I can't find any references. Anyone know and can you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Preferred way of reading excel files is with OpenXML SDK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Hi guy, Does sharepoint support the API for reading excel?

Comment: AFAIK no. Why would you need another API if OpenXML does the job done.

Comment: Nothing, just to know does SP supported or not? if yes, it's easier and more friendly